# how to sort a mathematical expression with a sum sign in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I sort a mathematical expression like this:

```
s = "1+3+2+1+4+3+5+16+63+3"
```

to the desired:

```
s = "1+1+2+3+3+3+4+5+16+63"
```

in `Python3`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: how complex can the expression be? can it be that you have `-` signs in there as well?

Comment: Split the string by `'+'` convert to int array, sort then build the string again ...

Comment: `s = '+'.join(sorted(s.split('+'), key=lambda x: int(x)))`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis `s = '+'.join(sorted(s.split('+'), key=int))` would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your expression is a string. You first need to extract numbers from your string and manipulate it : sorting numbers -> converting to string

```
>>> s = "1+3+2+1+4+3+5+16+63+3"
>>> chars = s.split('+')
>>> numbers = list(map(int, chars))
>>> sorted_numbers = sorted(numbers)
>>> "+".join(list(map(str,sorted_numbers)))
'1+1+2+3+3+3+4+5+16+63'
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle numbers with float type, use this:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from decimal import Decimal

In [2]: s = "1+3+2+1+4+3+5+16+63.5+3"

In [3]: nums = [Decimal(i) for i in s.replace(' ', '').split('+')]

In [4]: d = 's = ' + '+'.join(str(i) for i in sorted(nums))

In [5]: d
Out[5]: 's = 1+1+2+3+3+3+4+5+16+63.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'+'.join(str(x) for x in sorted([int(x) for x in s.split('+')]))
```

Not sure if further optimizations are possible.